# how to install standard modem in windows xp

Tags: windows, modem

I am new to windows programming but have programming experience on linux platform.

Anybody can please clarify the following.

I need to install a modem in windows xp through c program or batch script. Modem i have is a serial modem.Whenever i connect the modem that is coming as a serial port.I have to install that modem using windows standard medem driver(Modem.sys).That i have done through control panel item "phone and modem" . But i want to do that installation  using  c program or batch script. Can anybody please give some suggestions? Or is that possible to create dial up connection without installation to connect to gprs network ?

Comment: Installation of Windows drivers can easily be done with [DevCon.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272)...

Comment: Drivers are installed by Plug and Play.  Don't help, just plug.

Comment: @HansPassant does plug and play work with peripherals connected via a serial port?

Comment: @Yuvaraj Hi, I too want to do the same process using c or batch file, Please refer this link for my post on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396845/api-to-create-a-new-modem ,but I didnt find any solutions yet. If you have done this can you please help me out in this?

Comment: @2vision2 Hi, What i did is, created the dial-up connection manually(from control pannel add modem). And the used the command  "rasdial 'Dial-up Connection name'" for connecting and "rasdial 'Dial-up Connection name' /disconnect " for disconnecting . The dll rasdial provides some apis also to make dial-up connection, but i have not tried since i am not good at windows side. -Yuva

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the MSDN article [How To Programmatically Install Modem Drivers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194941) which includes rhis call to runDll32.exe can help

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL modem.cpl,Modems, noui inf=c:\MyModem.INF sect=MyModem
```

The article is very old and references Windows NT version 4.0 but then again I'm not convinced you not a time traveler asking this question from the late 90's

Comment: I too want to do the same process using c or batch file, Please refer this link for my post on this stackoverflow.com/questions/11396845/api-to-create-a-new-modem ,but I didnt find any solutions yet. Can you please suggest me some way to do this.

Comment: @user1317084 did you try creating the INF and then using the rundll32 call?

Comment: I used mdmhayes.inf which is default windows inf file in this command to install modem.sys. but it doesnt work. Am i doing it right or should i create a seperate inf file? But the microsoft link you provided says to create unattended.txt? could you please make clear that part? please..

Comment: @user1317084 sorry I'm out my depth here. You might want to try and put a bounty on your question

Comment: please mention what I did is right or wrong. Please.. I found only few people reply on this topic. please.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page : http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q304294

I encountered the same problem as you did, and I've succeeded with this solution on win7 64bit system. You should download source files from this page and compile it with WDK (I use WDK7.1) . Attention, the original source is compiled by DDK, and it will failed linking under WDK. So you should add one line to file 'SOURCES':

```
  USE_MSVCRT = 1
```

When build passes, you'll get an executable 'mdminst.exe'.  Then you could install any modem you want by CLI:

```
C:\> mdminst <modem-inf-file> <COM port> <HardwareID>
```

Ex. to install an standard 33600bps modem on COM1, the command is:

```
mdminst c:\windows\inf\mdmgen.inf COM1 mdmgen336
```