# API to create a new modem

Tags: c#, .net, c, windows, winapi

Is there any APIs in windows to do the following steps ( Create a new modem ).

controlpanel -> Phone and Modem Options -> Modem(tab) -> Add -> mark Dont detect my device -> select ( communication cable between two computers ) from the list -> Select ports from the lsit -> finish.

How to do this progrmatically. Please refer me some APIs for this.

Comment: Not everything you can do in Control Panel has a corresponding api function.  It is in fact rare.  Most applets work by writing registry keys, something you can observe with SysInternals' ProcMon utility.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something with the TAPI (telephony API) from windows.

Take a look here (for some specific modem APIs):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734853(v=vs.85).aspx

and here (for all TAPI interfaces available):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734273(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page : http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q304294

I encountered the same problem as you did, and I've succeeded with this solution on win7 64bit system. You should download source files from this page and compile it with WDK (I use WDK7.1) . Attention, the original source is compiled by DDK, and it will failed linking under WDK. So you should add one line to file 'SOURCES':

```
  USE_MSVCRT = 1
```

When build passes, you'll get an executable 'mdminst.exe'.  Then you could install any modem you want by CLI:

```
C:\> mdminst <modem-inf-file> <COM port> <HardwareID>
```

Ex. to install an standard 33600bps modem on COM1, the command is:

```
mdminst c:\windows\inf\mdmgen.inf COM1 mdmgen336
```