# Installing new modem with MSDN article (194941) in XP and Windows 7

Tags: windows, embedded, usb, driver, modem

I'm trying to install a new modem programatically and I took [this windows documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194941) as reference. 
In the documentation it was mentioned as the procedure is for WindowsNT. Can I use the same procedure for windows xp and windows 7? does the unattended.txt works in xp and windows 7?

This procedure is also reffered in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688048/how-to-install-standard-modem-in-windows-xp)

If the above is not possible in windows xp and windows 7 can you please suggest me a way to Install a new modem programatically?

Comment: Plug and Play was added to Windows since then.  Why that doesn't work for you is entirely unclear.  Look at SetupInstallFile()

Comment: @HansPassant Iam getting only the modem window after running this command rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL modem.cpl,Modems, noui inf=c:\MyModem.INF sect=MyModem

Comment: @HansPassant I want only the emodem to be installed in unattended state. Any extra parameters do I want to add to the Uattended.txt file?

Comment: What is the embedded tag on this for?